# reference showing as question marks in Latex and reference section not showing up in PDF

Tags: bibtex

I'm quite new to Latex and I have just started writing my thesis in latex. However, I have this problem with reference management. The references are not appearing inside the document, instead we have question marks.
I have followed the instructions  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number) and tried everything they mentioned.
I have included my `.bib` file at the right place and I have tried
PDFLatex > bibtex > PDFLatex > PDFLatex

When I run `PDFLatex` I get errors `undefined references` and when I run `bibtex` it is running fine. How can we fix this?
I'm using TexmMaker
on Ubuntu 18.0
This is my 'blg' file

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: TempleThesis_Clean.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: IPStatement/ipstatement.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Acknowledgement/acknowledgement.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Abstract/abstract.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Abbreviations/Abbreviations.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter_1/Chapter_1_File.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter_4/Chapter_4_File.aux
The style file: thesis.bst
You've used 7 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            103 strings with 886 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
```

This is a minimum working example of my main file

```
\include{Macros/MacroFile1}

\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{Classes/myThesis}

\graphicspath{{./Chapters/Chapter_1/Chapter_1_Fig/}     
              {./Chapters/Chapter_2/Chapter_2_Fig/}
              {./Chapters/Chapter_3/Chapter_3_Fig/}
              {./ThesisFigs/}}

\newcommand{\theAuthor}{My name}
\newcommand{\authorEmail}{mymail@my.com}
\newcommand{\myTitle}{My Title}
\pdfinfo { /Title  (\myTitle)
           /Creator (TeX)
           /Producer (pdfTeX)
           /Author (\theAuthor \authorEmail)
           /ModDate (D:\pdfdate)
           /CreationDate (D:\pdfdate)  %format D:YYYYMMDDhhmmss
           /Subject (Condensed Matter Physics)
           /Keywords (PhD, Thesis)}    
        \pdfcatalog { /PageMode (/UseOutlines)
                  /OpenAction (fitbh)  }

\title{\myTitle}
\author{\href{mailto:\authorEmail}{\theAuthor}}
\crest{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{Leeds_Crest.png}}

\logo{\includegraphics[width=50mm]{UoL_logo}} %University Logo
\deptlogo{} %\includegraphics[width=50mm]{UoL_logo}} % Institute Logo

\collegeordept{\href{http://ipcms.unistra.fr}{Institut de Physique et Chimie des Materiaux de Strasbourg (IPCMS)}}
\university{\href{http://unistra.fr}{University of Strasbourg}}

\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\degreedate{\monthdate\today}



\linespread{1.3} %1.5 line spacing

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\frontmatter

\include{IPStatement/ipstatement}
\include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}
\include{Abstract/abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\include{Abbreviations/Abbreviations}

\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{Chapters/Chapter_test_file}




\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References} % Adds References to contents page
\bibliographystyle{thesis} % bibliography style
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
\bibliography{References/library} 
\end{document}
```

This is an example of my chapter file

```
\chapter{Introduction}
Thesis writing is lots of fun\cite{Febid1}
```

This is an example of my bib file

```
@PREAMBLE{
 "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}" 
 # "\providecommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}%" 
}

@article{fernandez-pacheco_three-dimensional_2017,
    title = {Three-dimensional nanomagnetism},
    volume = {8},
    copyright = {2017 The Author(s)},
    issn = {2041-1723},
    url = {https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15756},
    doi = {10.1038/ncomms15756},
    language = {en},
    number = {1},
    urldate = {2021-06-16},
    journal = {Nature Communications},
    author = {Fernández-Pacheco, Amalio and Streubel, Robert and Fruchart, Olivier and Hertel, Riccardo and Fischer, Peter and Cowburn, Russell P.},
    month = jun,
    year = {2017},
    note = {Number: 1
    Publisher: Nature Publishing Group},
    pages = {15756},
    file = {Full Text PDF:/home/rajgourav/Zotero/storage/N2WSEP79/Fernández-Pacheco et al. - 2017 - Three-dimensional nanomagnetism.pdf:application/pdf;Snapshot:/home/rajgourav/Zotero/storage/AK82XNP5/ncomms15756.html:text/html}
}

@article{Febid1,
author = {Utke, Ivo and Hoffmann, Patrik and Melngailis, John},
year = {2008},
month = {08},
pages = {1197 - 1276},
title = {Gas-assisted focused electron beam and ion beam processing and fabrication},
volume = {26},
journal = {Journal of Vacuum Science & Technology B: Microelectronics and Nanometer Structures},
doi = {10.1116/1.2955728}
}

@article{Febid_teresa_review_2016,
    title = {Review of magnetic nanostructures grown by focused electron beam induced deposition ({FEBID})},
    volume = {49},
    issn = {0022-3727},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F0022-3727%2F49%2F24%2F243003},
    doi = {10.1088/0022-3727/49/24/243003}, 
    number = {24},
    urldate = {2020-05-05},
    journal = {Journal of Physics D: Applied Physics},
    author = {Teresa, J. M. De and Fernández-Pacheco, A. and Córdoba, R. and Serrano-Ramón, L. and Sangiao, S. and Ibarra, M. R.},
    month = may,
    year = {2016},
    note = {Publisher: IOP Publishing},
    pages = {243003}    
}
```

Comment: the sequence needs to be pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex, but without seeing a small example that does the wrong thing it isn't really possible to say what you have done wrong. Have you  referenced the bibliography with `\bibliography{yourbibfile}` ?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestions I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't reproduce the error: your code is not working nor minimal. Please try to make it as simple as possible, removing those extra `\include` we don't have and using a standard class. You'll see if the error arises from the macros loaded at the very beginning for instance.

Comment: Using your library.bib and the very minimalist code `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
 Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Febid1}.
 
 \bibliography{library}
 \bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}` compiles fine here: there is only a complaint on a "&" character in the Febid1 journal name that should be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Update : The problem was solved when I replaced the `thesis` bib style with `nature` bib style and moved the `bibliographystyle` line to after `bibligraphy` line. I do not know enough Latex to explain what happened, but  this fixed the issue.